# Php: updating database with values from dynamically generated form fields

Tags: php

How do I save the following form?

```
<form name="myform">
<input type="text" name="title" value="title" />

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, text from details where parent='$parent' 
order by id asc") or die('Error');
while(list($id,$ftext) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
?>
<textarea name="formfield<?php echo $id;?>" id="<?php echo $id;?>">
<?php echo $ftext;?>
</textarea>
<?php
}
</form>
```

As you can see above, the MySQL query will load data and dynamically create textareas:

```
<textarea name="formfield34" id="34">text</textarea>
<textarea name="formfield56" id="56">more text</textarea>        
<textarea name="formfield78" id="78">anothet text</textarea>
```

I need to update database like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE details SET text='$formfield34' WHERE id ='34'") or die('Error');
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE details SET text='$formfield56' WHERE id ='56'") or die('Error');
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE details SET text='$formfield78' WHERE id ='78'") or die('Error');
```

The problem is that each form will have a different number of textareas loaded dynamically and different $ids. I can not imagine hot to save this form.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use `foreach` to step through $_POST to find fields called `formfieldxx`, and use a little text processing to write the content of `formfieldxx` to the database where `id=xx`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably need to do is to look at using array notation in your form field names like this:

```
<textarea name="formfield[34]" id="34">text</textarea>
<textarea name="formfield[56]" id="56">more text</textarea>        
<textarea name="formfield[78]" id="78">anothet text</textarea>
```

PHP will automatically build an array in `$_POST['formfield']`. that you can access with all this data.  This make it easy to loop through this array and generate SQL for your updates.

```
foreach($_POST['formfield'] as $key => $value) {
    // write SQL here
}
```

Now, rather than a bunch of individual SQL queries, you might want to consider using `REPLACE` syntax so that you can insert/update your data with a single query.

Answer (score 0):

in the "while" while creating the textarea save an array with the id of these textarea.

Then retrace the array to use ids when you need it